# How do I get a list of countries a user visited based on multiple database tables?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables (some fields were omitted):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    username character varying(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE flights (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    user_id uuid NOT NULL,
    departure_airport_id uuid,
    arrival_airport_id uuid,
    departure_date date,
    departure_time time(0) without time zone,
    arrival_date date,
    arrival_time time(0) without time zone,
    flight_number character varying(255)
);

CREATE TABLE airports (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    country_id uuid,
    code character varying(255)
);

CREATE TABLE countries (
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    code character varying(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE country_user (
    country_id uuid NOT NULL,
    user_id uuid NOT NULL,
    visited_at date NOT NULL
);
```

Users can add flights. Each flight has a departure and an arrival airport and each airport has a country.
Additionally, users can log countries outside of flights. These get stored in an intermediate table `country_user`.

Now, I need to make a list of all countries the user has been to, either by flying or just by logging it.
I also need to list the mode of transport, so either `flight` or `other`, the year it was first visited and the number of times a user has been there (results need to be ordered by this count as well; flights within a country must only be counted once).
Countries that were flown to take precedence over countries that were just logged via `country_user`, so if a user flew to Germany on `2020-01-01`, but also logged Germany for `2019-01-01`, then the year should be `2020` and the mode of transport should be `flight`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
select name, sum(c_count) as count, min(c_year) as year, transport_mode from (
    (
        select 
            countries.code as name, 
            count(countries.code) as c_count, 
            extract(year from min(flights.departure_date)) as c_year, 
            'flight' as transport_mode 
        from "flights" 
        left join "airports" on "flights"."departure_airport_id" = "airports"."id" 
        left join "countries" on "airports"."country_id" = "countries"."id" 
        where "flights"."departure_airport_id" is not null 
        and "flights"."user_id" = '...' 
        group by "countries"."code", transport_mode
    ) union (
        select 
            countries.code as name, 
            count(countries.code) as c_count, 
            extract(year from min(flights.departure_date)) as c_year, 
            'flight' as transport_mode 
        from "flights" 
        left join "airports" on "flights"."arrival_airport_id" = "airports"."id" 
        left join "countries" on "airports"."country_id" = "countries"."id" 
        where "flights"."arrival_airport_id" is not null 
        and "flights"."user_id" = '...' 
        group by "countries"."code", transport_mode
    ) union (
        select 
            countries.code as name, 
            count(countries.code) as c_count, 
            extract(year from min(country_user.visited_at)) as c_year, 
            'other' as transport_mode 
        from "country_user" 
        left join "countries" on "country_user"."country_id" = "countries"."id" 
        where "user_id" = '...' 
        group by "countries"."code", transport_mode
    )
) as "results" 
group by name, transport_mode
order by count DESC, name ASC;
```

If a country has been flown to and logged, then I get 2 separate results, tho. Also, countries that were flown to don't take precedence and I think that flights within a country might get counted twice.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the user makes a roundtrip flight, should the count for departure and arrival countries be 2?

Comment: Good question, hasn't come up with the client, but so far we treated each flight separately, so I'm guessing that the count should be 2 then.

Comment: I'll bet a beer you get an answer like "uhmmmm that depends how long they stayed in the country"

Answer (score 0):

That should work although it is not very nice. Maybe someone else could find a nicer solution.

The first two select counts when the origin and destination country is not the same while the third counts only once when the origin and departure country is the same.

```
select name, sum(c_count) as count, min(c_year) as year, transport_mode from (
(
        select 
            countries.code as name, 
            count(countries.code) as c_count, 
            extract(year from min(flights.departure_date)) as c_year, 
            'flight' as transport_mode
        from "flights" 
        left join "airports" on "flights"."departure_airport_id" = "airports"."id" 
        left join "countries" on "airports"."country_id" = "countries"."id" 
        where 
            (select "country_id" from "airports" where "airports"."id" = departure_airport_id) != (select "country_id" from "airports" where "airports"."id" = arrival_airport_id)
        and "flights"."user_id" = '...' 
        group by "countries"."code"
    ) union (
        select 
            countries.code as name, 
            count(countries.code) as c_count, 
            extract(year from min(flights.departure_date)) as c_year, 
            'flight' as transport_mode
        from "flights" 
        left join "airports" on "flights"."arrival_airport_id" = "airports"."id" 
        left join "countries" on "airports"."country_id" = "countries"."id" 
        where 
            (select "country_id" from "airports" where "airports"."id" = departure_airport_id) != (select "country_id" from "airports" where "airports"."id" = arrival_airport_id)
        and "flights"."user_id" = '...' 
        group by "countries"."code"
    ) union (
        select 
            countries.code as name, 
            count(countries.code) as c_count, 
            extract(year from min(flights.departure_date)) as c_year, 
            'flight' as transport_mode 
            from "flights" 
        left join "airports" on "flights"."arrival_airport_id" = "airports"."id" 
        left join "countries" on "airports"."country_id" = "countries"."id" 
        where (select "country_id" from "airports" where "airports"."id" = departure_airport_id) = (select "country_id" from "airports" where "airports"."id" = arrival_airport_id)
        and "flights"."user_id" = '...' 
        group by "countries"."code"
    ) union (
        select 
            countries.code as name, 
            count(countries.code) as c_count, 
            extract(year from min(country_user.visited_at)) as c_year, 
            'other' as transport_mode 
        from "country_user" 
        left join "countries" on "country_user"."country_id" = "countries"."id" 
        where "user_id" = '...' 
        group by "countries"."code", transport_mode
    )
) as "results" 
group by name, transport_mode
order by count DESC, name ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks, need to check it properly tomorrow. It still gave me multiple rows for a country if there was a flight and a separate visit, but I added `array_agg(distinct transport_mode) as mode` and that combined the rows. I guess I could check the presence of `flight` in `mode` in the web app then.